# FFT Service on AWS?

Tags: signal-analysis

Hopefully this is the right forum to post this question. Initially posted to Meta. My mistake. Learned the hard way via downvoting.

I searched AWS and Microsoft cognitive services for an FFT web service but can't seem to find one. Is such a service available?

I am trying to build an Alexa/Cortana skill with an interaction like so

1. Ask Alexa to invoke skill via launch word
2. Alexa responds "Please say something"
3. User responds with a short sentence
4. I would like to perform an FFT of the user response, call a lambda function to perform analysis and respond via Alexa's text to speech.

Is a service available on AWS or MS Cognitive services or elsewhere that can perform the FFT?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about signal processing.

Comment: This is more of a question about cloud service offerings more than signal processing. It's not clear what exactly you want to do, but as far as I know, those services are primarily speech-to-text; they don't give you the raw speech signal itself, only the transliteration of the words that the service believes were spoken.

Comment: The thing that executes your lambda function (whatever that is in this particular context) would be the place to execute the FFT. I think you might be overestimating the complexity of an FFT: you really don't need to anyone else to calculate that on a few hundred thousand samples. Whatever the alexa thing runs on will be plenty powerful.